# Shortcode Within Shortcode or Nested Shortcode (notes in //comments)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, shortcode

I am a COMPLETE beginner with PHP but am trying my absolute best to learn, so please be kind (I am aware that my code may be laughably incorrect/poor, but hey—gotta start somewhere)!

I need to figure out, in PHP, the most effective way to organize the following situation. My goal is to be able to:
(1) edit all 24 pages from one file and,
(2) edit the "constant" html formatting in one place as a variable itself. They all use the same formatting, but display different results (such as various tax rates per county; the words `<p>Recordation Tax Rate: </p>` are constant and the `$specificRate` is a variable, so for example: `<p>Recordation Tax Rate: $specificRate</p>`
I'm able to accomplish this with the following (note that this is only one section of one function of the 24 total counties—it is very large, which is why I want to have everything accessible in one place):

```
<?php

// Here I have my specific variables for each item
// ALLEGANY COUNTY

function shortcode_1a( $atts ) {
// These are my "global" variables for the template

        $factPopulation = 'Population (2020):';
        $factZip = 'Zip Codes:';

        $utilityElectric = 'Electric';
        $utilityGas = 'Gas';
        $utilityWater = 'Water';

        $wasteDepartment = 'Department';
        $wasteTrash = 'Trash';
        $wasteRecycle = 'Recycle';
        $wasteLandfill = 'Landfill';

        $taxDepartment = 'Department';
        $taxReference = 'References';
        $taxRate = 'Current Rates (2020)';

        $schoolDepartment = 'Department';
        $schoolReference = 'References';
```

Below are the specific inputs for allegany_county_resources via `shortcode_1a`. It also shows my more specific variables. File is the same as above.

```
// (continued)

          $factPopulationNumber = '68,106';
              $factPopulationNumberLink = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census/decade/2020/2020-census-main.html';
          $factZipNumber = '21502, 21529, 21530, 21532, 21543, 21545, 21555, 21557, 21562, 21766';

          $utilityElectricName = 'Potomac Edison';
              $utilityElectricNameLink = 'https://www.firstenergycorp.com/potomac_edison.html';
          $utilityElectricNumber = '+1 (800) 686-0011';
          $utilityElectricEmail = '';
          $utilityElectricContact = 'Contact Form';
              $utilityElectricContactLink = 'https://www.firstenergycorp.com/corporate/contact_us.html';
          $utilityElectricAddress = '10802 Bower Avenue <br>Williamsport, MD 21795';
          $utilityElectricHours = 'Monday - Friday <br>8:00AM - 6:00PM';

          $utilityGasName = 'Columbia Gas of Maryland';
              $utilityGasNameLink = 'https://www.columbiagasmd.com/';
          $utilityGasNumber = '+1 (888) 460-4332';
          $utilityGasEmail = '';
          $utilityGasContact = 'Contact Form';
              $utilityGasContactLink = 'https://www.columbiagasmd.com/help/contact-us/contact-us-form';
          $utilityGasAddress = '55 Sycamore Street <br>Hagerstown, MD 21740';
          $utilityGasHours = 'Monday - Friday <br>7:00AM - 7:00PM';

          $utilityWaterName = 'Allegany County <br>Tax and Utility Office';
              $utilityWaterNameLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/182/Pay-Online';
          $utilityWaterNumber = '+1 (301) 777-5965';
          $utilityWaterEmail = '';
          $utilityWaterContact = 'Rate Lookup';
              $utilityWaterContactLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/DocumentCenter/View/524/Water-and-Sewer-Rates-FY22-PDF?bidId=';
          $utilityWaterAddress = '701 Kelly Road <br>Cumberland, MD 21502';
          $utilityWaterHours = 'Monday - Friday <br>8:00AM - 4:00PM';

          $wasteDepartmentName = 'Allegany County <br>Recycling Office';
              $wasteDepartmentNameLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/286/Recycling-Office';
          $wasteDepartmentNumber = '+1 (301) 777-5933';
          $wasteDepartmentEmail = 'recycling@alleganygov.org';
          $wasteDepartmentContact = '';
              $wasteDepartmentContactLink = '';
          $wasteDepartmentAddress = '701 Kelly Road <br>Cumberland, MD 21502';
          $wasteDepartmentHours = 'Monday - Friday <br>8:00AM - 4:00PM';

          $wasteTrashName = 'Service Provider';
              $wasteTrashNameLink = 'https://www.applevalleywaste.com/residential/maryland/allegany-county/';
          $wasteTrashNumber = '';
          $wasteTrashEmail = '';
          $wasteTrashContact = '';
              $wasteTrashContactLink = '';
          $wasteTrashAddress = '';
          $wasteTrashHours = '';

          $wasteRecycleName = 'Drop-Off Map';
              $wasteRecycleNameLink = 'http://alleganygis.allconet.org/recycle/index.html';
          $wasteRecycleNumber = '';
          $wasteRecycleEmail = '';
          $wasteRecycleContact = '';
              $wasteRecycleContactLink = '';
          $wasteRecycleAddress = '';
          $wasteRecycleHours = '';

          $wasteLandfillName = 'Waste Guide (PDF)';
              $wasteLandfillNameLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/DocumentCenter/View/813/Recycling-Brochure-PDF?bidId=';
          $wasteLandfillNumber = '';
          $wasteLandfillEmail = '';
          $wasteLandfillContact = '';
              $wasteLandfillContactLink = '';
          $wasteLandfillAddress = '';
          $wasteLandfillHours = '';

          $taxDepartmentName = 'Allegany County<br> Tax and Utilities Office';
              $taxDepartmentNameLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/181/Tax-Utility-Office';
          $taxDepartmentNumber = '+1 (301) 777-5965';
          $taxDepartmentEmail = '';
          $taxDepartmentContact = 'Contact Directory';
              $taxDepartmentContactLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/directory.aspx';
          $taxDepartmentAddress = '701 Kelly Road<br> Cumberland, MD 21502';
          $taxDepartmentHours = 'Monday - Friday <br>8:00AM - 4:00PM';

          $taxReferenceBill = 'Tax Bill Lookup';
              $taxReferenceBillLink = 'https://alleganymd.munisselfservice.com/citizens/RealEstate/Default.aspx?mode=new';
          $taxReferenceRecord = 'Database Lookup';
              $taxReferenceRecordLink = 'https://sdat.dat.maryland.gov/RealProperty/Pages/default.aspx';
          $taxReferenceInformation = 'Transfer + Recordation Taxes';
              $taxReferenceInformationLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/189/Miscellaneous-Taxes-Fee-Rates';
          $taxReferenceCredit = 'Tax Credits + Resources';
              $taxReferenceCreditLink = 'https://alleganygov.org/1545/Incentives#:~:text=At%20Allegany%20Countys%20North%20Branch,increased%20value%20of%20the%20property.';
          $taxReferenceQuestion = 'Property Tax (FAQ)';
              $taxReferenceQuestionLink = 'https://www.alleganygov.org/101/How-Do-I';

          $taxRatePropertyCounty = '<strong>Property Tax: </strong><br>$0.975 per $100 of assessed value';
          $taxRatePropertyState = '';
          $taxRateTransferCounty = '<strong>County Transfer Tax: </strong><br>0.5% of consideration';
          $taxRateTransferState = '<strong>State Transfer Tax: </strong><br>0.5% of consideration';
          $taxRateRecordation = '<strong>Recordation Tax: </strong><br>$3.50 for each $500 of consideration';

          $schoolDepartmentName = 'Allegany County<br> Public Schools';
              $schoolDepartmentNameLink = 'https://www.acpsmd.org/';
          $schoolDepartmentNumber = '+1 (301) 759-2000';
          $schoolDepartmentEmail = '';
          $schoolDepartmentContact = '';
              $schoolDepartmentContactLink = '';
          $schoolDepartmentAddress = '108 Washington Street <br>Cumberland, MD 21502';
          $schoolDepartmentHours = '';

          $schoolReferenceDirectory = 'School Directory';
              $schoolReferenceDirectoryLink = 'https://www.acpsmd.org/site/Default.aspx?PageType=1&SiteID=4&ChannelID=15&DirectoryType=6';
          $schoolReferenceCalendar = 'School Calendars (2021)';
              $schoolReferenceCalendarLink = 'https://www.acpsmd.org/Page/2#calendar1/20210913/month';
          $schoolReferenceStatistic = 'Statistics + Demographics';
              $schoolReferenceStatisticLink = 'https://nces.ed.gov/Programs/Edge/ACSDashboard/2400030';

// I want to echo a standard template that has its own variables, like so:

        echo "$myHtmlTemplate"
;}

add_shortcode( 'allegany_county_resources', 'shortcode_1a');

?>
```

Below is `$myHtmlTemplate`. I want `$myHtmlTemplate` to echo out for each county's function. Currently the echo appears, but none of the variables carry over.

```
<?php

function shortcode_1(){
       $myHtmlTemplate = 

"
<div class='section-content'>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$factPopulation</h3>
  <p class='section paragraph'>$factPopulationNumber<a href='$factPopulationNumberLink'>ⓘ</a></p>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$factZip</h3>
  <p class='section paragraph'>$factZipNumber</p>

</div>
<div class='section-content'>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$utilityElectric</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$utilityElectricNameLink'>$utilityElectricName</a><br><a href='tel:$utilityElectricNumber'>$utilityElectricNumber</a><br><a class='section button' href='$utilityElectricContactLink'>$utilityElectricContact</a><br>
    <br>$utilityElectricAddress<br>
    <br>$utilityElectricHours</li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$utilityGas</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$utilityGasNameLink'>$utilityGasName</a><br><a href='tel:$utilityGasNumber'>$utilityGasNumber</a><br><a class='section button' href='$utilityGasContactLink'>$utilityGasContact</a><br>
    <br>$utilityGasAddress<br>
    <br>$utilityGasHours</li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$utilityWater</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$utilityWaterNameLink'>$utilityWaterName</a><br><a href='tel:$utilityWaterNumber'>$utilityWaterNumber</a><br><a class='section button' href='$utilityWaterContactLink'>$utilityWaterContact</a><br>
    <br>$utilityWaterAddress<br>
    <br>$utilityWaterHours</li><br>
  </ul>

</div>
<div class='section-content'>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$wasteDepartment</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$wasteDepartmentNameLink'>$wasteDepartmentName</a><br><a href='tel:$wasteDepartmentNumber'>$wasteDepartmentNumber</a><br>$wasteDepartmentEmail<br>
    <br>$wasteDepartmentAddress<br>
    <br>$wasteDepartmentHours</li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$wasteTrash</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a class='section button' href='$wasteTrashNameLink'>$wasteTrashName</a><br></li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$wasteRecycle</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a class='section button' href='$wasteRecycleNameLink'>$wasteRecycleName</a><br></li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$wasteLandfill</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$wasteLandfillNameLink'>$wasteLandfillName</a></li><br>
  </ul>

</div>
<div class='section-content'>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$taxDepartment</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$taxDepartmentNameLink'>$taxDepartmentName</a><br><a href='tel:$taxDepartmentNumber'>$taxDepartmentNumber</a><br><a class='section button' href='$taxDepartmentContactLink'>$taxDepartmentContact</a><br>
    <br>$taxDepartmentAddress<br>
    <br>$taxDepartmentHours</li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$taxReference</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li>Property Records<br><a class='section button' href='$taxReferenceBillLink'>$taxReferenceBill</a><br><a class='section button' href='$taxReferenceRecordLink'>$taxReferenceRecord</a></li><br>
    <li><a href='$taxReferenceInformationLink'>$taxReferenceInformation</a></li><br>
    <li><a href='$taxReferenceCreditLink'>$taxReferenceCredit</a></li><br>
    <li><a href='$taxReferenceQuestionLink'>$taxReferenceQuestion</a></li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$taxRate</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li>$taxRatePropertyCounty</li><br>
    <li>$taxRateTransferCounty</li><br>
    <li>$taxRateTransferState</li><br>
    <li>$taxRateRecordation</li><br>
  </ul>

</div>
<div class='section-content'>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$schoolDepartment</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$schoolDepartmentNameLink'>$schoolDepartmentName</a><br><a href='tel:$schoolDepartmentNumber'>$schoolDepartmentNumber</a><br>
    <br>$schoolDepartmentAddress</li><br>
  </ul>

  <h3 class='section heading'>$schoolReference</h3>
  <hr><br>

  <ul class='section list'>
    <li><a href='$schoolReferenceDirectoryLink'>$schoolReferenceDirectory</a></li><br>
    <li><a href='$schoolReferenceCalendarLink'>$schoolReferenceCalendar</a></li><br>
    <li><a href='$schoolReferenceStatisticLink'>$schoolReferenceStatistic</a></li><br>
  </ul>

</div>

";
    
    echo $myHtmlTemplate; 
}

add_shortcode('resources_template', 'shortcode_1');

?>
```

Final shortcode used on page: 
[resources_template][allegany_county_resources][/resources_template]

To the person who takes the time to answer this: thank you **so** much.

Comment: Hi... this is a nice first attempt, however, this approach doesn't seem that great to me. How would you get all of the variables from shortcode to shortcode?  Aside from that... you can't echo shortcode output, you have to return it.  What I first though you wanted was to be able to include content from one shortcode wrapped in another.  However you need to include in the wrapper shortcode, a place to output the `$content` with `do_shortcode($content)`  https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/enclosing-shortcodes/#processing-enclosed-content

Comment: Oh, okay! Still incredibly confused though. I did come across do_shortcode() numerous times but there are surprisingly few videos online explaining how to apply it. 

Question: should I think of do_shortcode() as a separate shortcode that I connect to my county shortcodes? Or should I think of it as something I add into each county shortcode?